# How Adele sings "There's a fire" in the song "Rolling In The Deep"

Tags: pronunciation, accent

I like Adele and her song "[Rolling In The Deep](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rYEDA3JcQqw)".

She sings the first phrase "There's a fire".
And I can't hear it but "They they fire".
It's different from how a cover singer sings "[There's a fire](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lMrCW07XBS8)"
that I think is common.

Is this Adele's original accent or something? Or simple "a" emphasis?

Comment: If it helps, try not to think of English as words or even syllables, e.g. "There's a fire st(arting) ..." --> "therzeifairst...".

Comment: Adele is actually *imitating* another accent there, from the American South. She is singing in a style reminiscent of the blues genre.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What I hear is something like 'There zay fire'.

She's singing the word 'a' with a long ay sound.  This is not how British people normally talk (except occasionally to emphasize that there's only one of something), but it is sometimes used in songs as the long sound is easier to get a good sound from.  She's made a stylistic choice to suit her own singing voice.

The cover singer uses the short a sound (more like a schwa, actually).  This is how most people would say or sing it.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful answer. This made my fog completely sunny. Sorry for my literally Japanese expression. Thank you again.